# How do I auto refresh the displayed value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I am writing an ASP page to put in my PLC Beckhoff (running windows CE). The code is:

```
<%@ language=JScript %>
<%
     var nIntActual = 0;
     TcClient = new ActiveXObject("TcScript.TcScriptSync");
     TcClient.ConnectTo("", 801);
     nIntActual = TcClient.ReadVar(".PLCVarInt");
%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>TwinCAT ADS-Script-DLL - Sample 04 - Windows CE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        actual: <% Response.Write( nIntActual ); %>
    </body>
</html>
```

I load and reload the page and the value appears. Everything is ok.

But now, how can I refresh value (not the page), every 2 seconds?

I tried the `setInterval` function and I got the "object" ERROR.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please also include the code you have tried and didn't work.

Comment: i tried  TcClient = new ActiveXObject("TcScript.TcScriptSync");
   TcClient.ConnectTo("", 801);
   
   function Ordinal()
 {
   nIntActual = TcClient.ReadVar("xxxTeste.ddd");
    }
 var timerID = 0;
    timerID = setInterval(Ordinal(), 5000);

Comment: get the error: Parse error in script

Microsoft JScript runtime error: '800a138f'

Description: Object expected

In file: /index99.asp 
On line: 11